# Mercurial Remote Repository Directory

Tags: version-control, mercurial, repository, remote-access

I have a project with some team members and I want to setup a remote repository for our code.

If I want the code to ONLY be accessible by the team, in which directory should I create the repo (/var/www/?) and would enabling SSL and server authentication be enough to secure it?

Also is a certificate (selfsigned?) necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in which directory should I create the repo

In any. It's not a question of physical|logical location

> would enabling SSL and server authentication be enough to secure it?

No

Comment: it might be impossible to make it completely secure, but what else could I do?

Comment: @user2994682 - re-think about concepts. Samples (fast, dirty, on the fly ideas): 1. Lazy and cheap way - use Bitbucked private repo 2. Cheapest way - work in pure DVCS-mode, start-stop **local** `hg serve on demand` on exotic port 3. Geeky-way - use ssh:// repository with auth by keys (different keys for different users)